# IntelliJ vertical line colouring - how to change it

Tags: intellij-idea2017

How do i change the color of the vertical white lines in IntelliJ 2017.3

[image]

I found this guide but I think it's an older version. Haven't been able to find anything for 2017

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207073015-Style-vertical-indent-guides

Answer (score 2):

found the answer after more googling, posting here if anyone else has trouble as it can be tricky to find

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In PHPStorm 2023.1 (but I guess it applies to all JetBrains IDE) you can find all the vertical lines settings under `Editor > Color Scheme > General > Editor > Guides`.

The vertical lines mentioned in the question is the setting `Indent guide`.

[image: settings_screenshot]